# Use two jQuery functions to change single element opacity at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this function to gradually fade a logo as the user scrolls down:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#logo-black').css({'opacity':(( 60-scroll )/60)});
});
```

I need to fade the same logo out completely when a button is toggled, so I did this:

*jQuery*

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('.logo-black').toggleClass('logo-black-active');
});
```

*CSS*

```
.logo-black{
    opacity: 1;
}
.logo-black-active{
    opacity: 0;
}
.logo-black-hide{
    -webkit-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    -moz-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    -o-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    -ms-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
```

These two functions conflict, and the logo is revealed post-toggle if the user scrolls at all... How can I get these two functions to modify the opacity of one element at the same time without canceling each other out?

(The element I'm modifying has both an id & class of 'logo-black')

Comment: ^ I'd avoid the `!important` and use precedence to override: `.logo-black.logo-black-active { opacity: 0; }`

Comment: I'll try using precedence & report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use precedence to override

```
.logo-black.logo-black-active { opacity: 0; }
```

However [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) will add inline CSS rule which has precedence, so change the selector

```
$('#logo-black:not(.logo-black-active)').css({'opacity':(( 60-scroll )/60)});
```